# $H^{-3/2}$ control of the laplacian of a function by means of $H^{1/2}$ norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am wondering for my research if, given a smooth bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ then, for a sufficiently regular function $u$ we can write
$$
\Vert \Delta u\Vert_{H^{-3/2}(\Omega)}\leq C\Vert u \Vert_{H^{1/2}(\Omega)},
$$
for some positive constant $C$. I know a similar result related to the control of $H^{-1}$ norm, which can be obtained by duality, but in the fractional case I do not know how to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: I think this bound holds. You should be able to easily prove this bound for $\Omega = \mathbb R^2$ by taking Fourier transforms. Not sure about general $\Omega$. You can probably use extension operators to define $\Delta u$ and $u$ on all of $\mathbb R^2$ and then apply the result for $\Omega =\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you! I was also thinking about showing the result for $H^{-1}$ and $H^{-2}$ (by duality or starting from Fourier Transform) and then use interpolation to get the result...